# Check for Multiple Conditions in RouteOnAttribute in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

There are two conditions in `RouteOnAttribute` in NiFi. If both the conditions are met, then the `ExecuteSQL` processor should run, else `MonitorActivity` processor should run. If one of the conditions fail, MonitorActivity should run. How can I check both the conditions at the same time? When I tried `Route to 'matched' if all match`, it is routing to `unmatched` regardless.

[image: RouteOnAttribute Configuration]

[image: NiFi Flow]

Comment: try to put these 2 condition together to make just one route. Also note that MonitorActivity is meant to watch stream and detect inactivity not to notify conditions

Comment: @yaprak I tried that already, then it will kick off the next processor regardless. If only one condition is matching then also it will kick off the next processor which in my case is ```ExecuteSQL```. Yeah I am using ```MonitorActivity``` to watch the stream and kick off the flow from the beginning, if the output of ```RouteOnAttribute``` is ```unmatched```. My expected output is to kick off the next processor (```ExecuteSQL```) only if both the conditions are met. Hope I have explained my scenario so you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong with your **RouteOnAttribute** processor. It should work with the property `Route to 'matched' if all match`. I would advise you to recheck your expressions  and if both of them ever evaluate to be true.

However, here's an alternate solution if the above doesn't work:

Route both success relationships to a **[MergeContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html)** processor with `Minimum Number of Entries = 1` and `Maximum Number of Entries = 1`.

Route unmatched relationship to MonitorActivity

[image]